# javascript indexOf strange behavior

Tags: javascript, string, mocha.js, indexof, chai

I found a strange unexplainable behavior while writing a piece of test code for my javascript program.  I was comparing an output of res.body to check if it contains a string.

More precisely, I was checking if res.body contained a string 'channel'.

Even though the output did really contain that string, the test case was always failing.  I ran the program in debug mode, to examine why it is failing.  The results are puzzling, to say the least.

```
> res.body
'Error: invalid channnel'
> res.body.indexOf('channel')
-1
> res.body.indexOf('channe')
-1
> res.body.indexOf('chann')
15
>
```

if I try to check indexOf of 'channel' in res.body whose value was 'Error: invalid channel', I was supposed to get a positive value, but it gives -1.

so, I tried by reducing the no. of chars in the match, it still fails until I reduce the search string to contain just 'chann' i.e by omitting 'el'.

But this behavior doesn't happen, if I take a string litteral and do the same exercise.  For example, the below works perfectly.

```
> 'Error: invalid channel'.indexOf('channel')
15
```

I went ahead and checked the typeof res.body, and it shows as string, and not any object.

```
> typeof res.body
'string'
>
```

Did anyone face a similar problem ever? Or is there an explanation to this?

**EDIT**
It happens when I res.body as produced by mocha + chai framework.  The full code is below:

```
 58   it ("Should fail with 400, if invalid channel", function(done) {
 59     chai.request(app).post('/campaigns/js')
 60     .send(samples.type0.invalidChannel)
 61     .end(function(err, res) {
 62       console.log("response:", res.body);
 63       expect(res).to.have.status(400);
>64       debugger;
 65       expect(res.body).to.contain('channel');
 66       return done();
 67     });
 68   });
```

Comment: *cha**nnn**el* is not the same as *cha**nn**el*.

Comment: `'Error: invalid channnel'` Channel spelled incorrectly

Answer (score 3):

You're `res.body` has `channel` with 3 `n`s.

> 'Error: invalid channnel'

This means that `chann` matches, but `channe` won't because of the extra `n`.

Comment: Oh, my bad eye sight.  May be I am growing old :(

Answer (score 0):

In the first piece of code, "channnel"  has 3 n's. That's why it matched "chann"  but not "channe".

Comment: Thx to all of you. I wasted 4 hours on this.  Sometimes I can get as stupid as this.